# Is there a way to copy a VM (including all snapshots) to an ESX server?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-server

I'm trying to find a way to copy a VM with all snapshots to an ESX server. Up until now I've only been able to copy the actual status of the machine but havent been able to copy over the snapshots.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy it from where? Also, if you're running vSphere 5 then stop calling it ESX.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried copying the entire VM directory from on datatore to another using the datastore browser? Obviously the VM will need to be down but it should work fine, though I can't say I've tried it - but there's no other VM-specific metadata anywhere else that would matter.